# Create pug conditional based on existence cookie

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to a different homepage based on whether or not the user is logged in, to do so I tried to use pug conditionals to display different elements based on if the user is logged in. When the user is logged in, a cookie is created with the name userName, which also holds the users userName.
I have tried the following function to check whether the user is logged in:

```
    function loggedIn() {
      if (document.cookie.indexOf('userName=') ==  -1) {
         var isLoggedIn = false;
      }
      else {
        var isLoggedIn = true;
      }
      return isLoggedIn;
    }
```

And for passing this value to pug, I pass it along with the GET method:

```
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
       res.render('index', { title: 'Cinema', login: loggedIn()});     
    });
```

The error I get now, is that the page will not load, only displaying 'Document is not defined'.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by getting rid of the loggedIn function and changing the routing function to the following:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.cookies.userName) {
     res.render('index', { title: 'Cinema', login: true});
  }
  else {
     res.render('index', {title: 'Cinema', login: false});
  }
});
```